# calculating eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

how do you calculate eigenspaces?

Comment: Find vector solutions for (A-I) = 0 and (A-2I) = 0

Answer (score 3):

You can find the Eigenspace (the space generated by the eigenvector(s)) corresponding to each Eigenvalue by finding the kernel of the matrix $A-\lambda I$. This is equivalent to solving $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ for $x$.

In your case:

For $\lambda =1$ the eigenvectors are $(1,0,2)$ and $(0,1,-3)$ and the eigenspace is $gen\{(1,0,2);(0,1,-3)\}$
For $\lambda =2$ the eigenvector is $(0,-2,5)$ and the eigenspace is $gen\{(0,-2,5)\}$

Answer (score 1):

Denote $A$ your matrix. To find the eigenspace of $\lambda$ solve for $X=(x,y,z)^T$ the equation
$$AX=\lambda X$$